# Jenkins- flutter: command not found

Tags: jenkins, flutter

I am trying to configure a simple startup project. I am pulling the code from GIT and trying to create a build. Getting this error on **local Jenkins**,

```
[Flutter-Starter] $ /bin/sh /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/jenkins102165218853380431.sh
/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/jenkins102165218853380431.sh: line 3: flutter: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

My **Execute Shell** has

```
#!/bin/sh

flutter build apk --debug
```

Flutter is installed and is working on my system. As the same command is creating the android build for me on Studio.

Here is the environment, from **.bash_profile** file.

```
...
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/rana.singh/Downloads/softwares/flutter/bin
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export PATH=$PATH:Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
```

Not sure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I was missing. Just in case it could help someone else.

Remind you **I had this in my .bash_profile** already still, it was needed on Jenkins.

**Goto Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global Properties >** 
[image]

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue, I've also followed the medium article, but I'm having this same issue, I have the HOME, ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables and still having the error showing that flutter command not found, please help

Comment: Still have same error

Comment: Doesn't work me either.

Answer (score 1):

I solved by add Global Properties:

key need to add[PATH+]

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).